# How to reset a group of comboboxes back to no selection tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, ttkbootstrap

I'm using ttkbootstrap with tkinter and I have 15 ttkbootstrap comboboxes that I want to reset to no selection if a button is pressed.  I tried this code I found somewhere, but it does nothing.  I did verify I'm hitting the function with a print statement though:

```
import tkinter
from tkinterr import *
import ttkbootstrap as ttk

def clear():
    print("In the clear function!)
    if isinstance(Widget, ttk.combobox):
    Widget.delete(0,end)
```

I'm assuming Widget isn't defined properly and that is the issue?  I tried using Combobox and ComboBoxWidget, then tried to [name a widget instance](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/naming-widgets.html) ,but nothing seems to work.

I put all of the comboboxes in a class so I can pass self to other methods.

```
The button code is:
    self.clear_button = ttk.Button(button_frame),
    command = lambda: clear(),
etc...
```

I know I can reset an individual combobox using:

```
 def clear_combo():
        combobox.delete(0, "end")
```

I can loop through each combobox by unique name, but I was looking to find a better solution as that seemed clunky.  Is there a way to generically select a specific type of ttk widget for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can put all of the comboboxes in a frame, then you can ask the frame to give you all of its child widgets and you can iterate over them all in a loop.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def clear():
    for widget in combo_frame.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(widget, ttk.Combobox):
            widget.set("")

root = tk.Tk()
combo_frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief="groove")
combo_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

clear_button = tk.Button(combo_frame, text="clear", command=clear)
clear_button.pack(side="top")
for i in range(10):
    combo = ttk.Combobox(combo_frame, values=("one", "two", "three"))
    combo.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was able to modify my class code, based on your answer and got it working.